# Default value for all queries via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to write a mongoose schema that for all call to find() or findOne() will pass a certain value in one of its fields. I tried using the 'default' property on the field declaration, but that didn't work for me.

Here's my schema:

```
var schema = Schema({
  created_at: Date,
  type: {type: String, default: "alert"},
  timestamp: Number,
  order: Number,
  description: String,
  status: String,

});
```

I would like every call to find() and findOne() to pass the value "alert" in the "type" field.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a simple wrapper method to your model which will be responsible for finding every document with `type: "alert"`. Something like this:

```
var Model = mongoose.model('Model', theSchema);
Model.alerts = function (q, callback) {
  q.type = "alert";
  this.find(q, callback);
}
```

Then you could get what you want with `Model.alerts({}, callback)`.